# How I can map data from JSON and build the result exactly as I describe

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a object from `JSON` data.

```
        {
          skills: {
            extracted: [
              {value: 'PHP'},
              {value: 'JavaScript'},
              {value: 'Python'}
            ]
          },

         experience : {
            jobs : [
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "September 2014 to January 2015"
            },

            company : {
              value : "Direct Skill Systems LLC"
            },
            title : {
              "value" : "Senior "
            }
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "October 2013 to January 2014"
            },
            company : {
              value : "Seven Smarts LLC"
            },
            skills : [
              {
                value : "C#4 "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "November 2012 to February 2013"
            },
            company : {
              value : "Haypost CJSC"
            },
            title : {
              value : "Software Developer"
            },
            skills : [
              {
                value : "C#2 "
              },
              {
                value : "WinForms "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "April 2007 to February 2012"
            },
            company : {
              value : "Digamma LLC"
            },
            skills : [
              {
                value : "C#3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "June 2005 to June 2007"
            },
            company : {
              value : "UITE"
            },
            skills : [

            ]
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "February 2005 to May 2005"
            },
            company : {
              value : "Opensourcearmenia"
            },
            title : {
              value : "Web Developer"
            },
            skills : [

            ]
          },
          {
            date_range : {
              value : "January 2002 - April 2002"
            },
            title : {},
            skills : []
          }
        ]
      },

   education: {
       institutions: [
      {
        name: {
          value: "American University"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "July 2000 - November 2000"
        }
      },
      {
        name: {
          value: "State Engineering University, Master"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "September 1985 - July 1992"
        }
      },
      {
        name: {
          value: "M. Sar #8 School"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "September 1975 - July 1985"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
        }
```

How I can `map` data from JSON and build the result exactly as I describe.

```
 {
        children: [
            {
                name: 'skills',
                children2: [
                    {name: 'PHP'},
                    {name: 'JavaScript'},
                    {name: 'Python'}                   
            }
        ]
    }
```

I took advantage of the answer [Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec).

```js
var input = {
  skills: {
    extracted: [{
        value: 'PHP'
      },
      {
        value: 'JavaScript'
      },
      {
        value: 'Python'
      }
    ]
  },

  experience: {
    jobs: [{
        date_range: {
          value: "September 2014 to January 2015"
        },

        company: {
          value: "Direct Skill Systems LLC"
        },
        title: {
          "value": "Senior "
        }
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "October 2013 to January 2014"
        },
        company: {
          value: "Seven Smarts LLC"
        },
        skills: [{
          value: "C#4 "
        }]
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "November 2012 to February 2013"
        },
        company: {
          value: "Haypost CJSC"
        },
        title: {
          value: "Software Developer"
        },
        skills: [{
            value: "C#2 "
          },
          {
            value: "WinForms "
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "April 2007 to February 2012"
        },
        company: {
          value: "Digamma LLC"
        },
        skills: [{
          value: "C#3"
        }]
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "June 2005 to June 2007"
        },
        company: {
          value: "UITE"
        },
        skills: [

        ]
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "February 2005 to May 2005"
        },
        company: {
          value: "Opensourcearmenia"
        },
        title: {
          value: "Web Developer"
        },
        skills: [

        ]
      },
      {
        date_range: {
          value: "January 2002 - April 2002"
        },
        title: {},
        skills: []
      }
    ]
  },

  education: {
    institutions: [{
        name: {
          value: "American University"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "July 2000 - November 2000"
        }
      },
      {
        name: {
          value: "State Engineering University, Master"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "September 1985 - July 1992"
        }
      },
      {
        name: {
          value: "M. Sar #8 School"
        },
        date_range: {
          value: "September 1975 - July 1985"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

var data = {
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Skills',
            children2: input.skills.extracted.map(skill => ({name:skill.value}))
        },
        {
            name: 'Experience',
            children2: input.experience.jobs.map(job => ({name:job.date_range.value} ))
        },
        {
            name: 'Education',
            children2: input.education.institutions.map(edu => ({name:edu.name.value, children2: [{name:edu.date_range.value}]} ))
        },
    ]
};

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Given you an answer which directly answers your question, but on re-reading the word "dynamically" stands out. Is there something about what you're trying to achieve you've not made clear? s `skills` really the only key?

Comment: Thank you, you helped me. Yes, I incorrectly formulated my question, but you understood me correctly :) no, `skills` are not the only key.. there are 3 keys, but they are unchangeable.

Comment: So did you want something more dynamic than just hardcoding `skills` (and your other two)? Its very possible - just update the question with what the input json *really* looks like and ill update my answer

Comment: *In the question* - blocks of json are not readable in comments! (edit link below question text)

Comment: I have already changed the text of the question.

Comment: Ok, not sure this can be made more dynamic - I was expecting the children to be the same, you have different logic for all 3 keys - so they way you've done it seems fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. These keys are unchangeable, there is no point in making it dynamic.. only children2 values will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want to `map` your `skills.extracted` array and build the result exactly as you describe:

```js
var input = {
  skills: {
    extracted: [
      {value: 'PHP'},
      {value: 'JavaScript'},
      {value: 'Python'}
    ]
  }
}

var output = {
        children: [
            {
                name: 'skills',
                children2: input.skills.extracted.map(skill => ({name:skill.value}))
            }
       ]
    }
    
console.log(output);
```